# Should I use Devise Gem for Enterprise Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, enterprise

I am building an enterprise application in rails that will have a few thousand users. I want to know what is the best authenticating platform. I can do a authenticating scaffold from scratch and have worked with Devise.

Only employees from specific companies should be able to log-on and request products. similar to amazon but specific for a few companies

What are the other options? What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise is a powerful authentication system that should be able to handle what you want done perfectly.